# Ensemble stacking model... with different inputs (molecular Fingerprint) in one type of keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, weighted-average, ensemble-learning

I am CHEMIST and still learning ML...

I have trained 7 different models with keras using different types of molecular fingerprints as features to predict a property...however the accuracy was not that good.

So using a tutorial i found online

```
def optimized_weights(prd,y_fold):
    # define bounds on each weight
    bound_w = [(0.0, 1.0) for _ in range(n_members) ]
    # arguments to the loss function
    search_arg = (prd ,y_fold)
    # global optimization of ensemble weights

    result = differential_evolution(loss_function, bound_w,search_arg,  maxiter=2000, tol=0.0001)
    # get the chosen weights
    weights = normalize(result['x'])
    return weights



def weighted_accuracy(prd,weights,y_fold):
    summed = tensordot(prd, weights, axes=((0),(0)))

    yhat=np.round(summed)

    score = accuracy_score(y_fold,yhat )
    f1 = f1_score(y_fold,yhat)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_fold,summed,pos_label=1)
    auc_test = auc(fpr, tpr)

    conf_matrix=confusion_matrix(y_fold,yhat)
    total=sum(sum(conf_matrix))
    sensitivity = conf_matrix[0,0]/(conf_matrix[0,0]+conf_matrix[0,1])


    specificity = conf_matrix[1,1]/(conf_matrix[1,0]+conf_matrix[1,1])

    return score,auc_test,sensitivity,specificity,f1
```

For weighted average ensemble model,i trained model on 80% of data and 20% was used to find optimized weights using differential_evolution (from scipy) for max accuracy, but i think this accuracy is biased toward test data...

I also repeated the same process for 5 fold cross validation and determined avg accuracy....
Is it acceptable...
if not, then please tell me what i can do

Thanks

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Could you please post a minimum working example of your code so that people can reproduce your issue? Exemplar inputs and expected output would also be useful.

Comment: Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.
I think that perhaps you want the statistics site.

Comment: I have added my code please tell me if is biased toward test data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DeepStack](https://github.com/jcborges/DeepStack) offers an interface for stacking and "ensembling" Keras Models. It also offers performance tests based on validation data out of the box

Comment: I can't find DeepStack now. Did the package move somewhere else?